# Selected option in angular select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I have select with ng-repeat:

```
<select class="span5 ui-select2 id="goal_{{goal.id}}" multiple="multiple">
  <option ng-repeat="counterGoal in counterGoals" value="{{counterGoal.id}}">{{counterGoal.name}}</option>
</select>
```

in `goal` model I have `counter_goal_ids` array like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

How can I select options that are included in `goal.counter_goal_ids`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

You can select the options by using the [ng-selected](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSelected) attribute and a custom function in your model

```
ng-selected="isInGoalIds({{counterGoal.id}})"
```

And in your model, add a function

```
$scope.isInGoalIds = function(id){
    angular.forEach($scope.counter_goal_ids, function(value, index){
      if(id == value){
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It will not run 100*100. This is only if your goal array is the same size as your initial array. 
There will be total_items * goal_items iterations max